# Error in Veins Demo Scenario

Tags: fatal-error, omnet++

I want to use veins to simulate V2V communication. I tried to practice veins tutorial step by step. I use omnetpp-4.4, sumo-0.21.0 and veins-3.0. In final step, veins demo scenario doesn't run. There are two problems including:

1. `enter code here`fatal error: jni.h: No such file or directory.
2. `make: ***[out/gcc-debug//jMessage.o] Error`

How can I fix the problems?

Answer (score 2):

JMessage is a part of OMNeT++ itself - there should be no reason to compile this after OMNeT++ is already running. Maybe you imported the OMNeT++ source code into the OMNeT++ IDE and are trying to build OMNeT++ with OMNeT++.

In any case, I think the best way foward is to try and delete OMNeT++, then start again with step 2.